# --optfile not working with gdal_retile?

Tags: gdal

I have the following [gdal_retile](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_retile.html) command I am trying to run, but it errors on the --optfile:

`gdal_retile.py -v -r bilinear -levels 8 -ps 512 512 -co "tiled=YES" -targetDir pyramid --optfile files.txt`

```
   Unrecognised command option: -
   Usage: gdal_retile.py
        [-v] [-co NAME=VALUE]* [-of out_format]
        [-ps pixelWidth pixelHeight]
        [-ot  {Byte/Int16/UInt16/UInt32/Int32/Float32/Float64/
               CInt16/CInt32/CFloat32/CFloat64}]
        [ -tileIndex tileIndexName [-tileIndexField fieldName]]
        [ -csv fileName [-csvDelim delimiter]]
        [-s_srs srs_def]  [-pyramidOnly] -levels numberoflevels
        [-r {near/bilinear/cubic/cubicspline/lanczos}]
        [-useDirForEachRow]
        -targetDir TileDirectory input_files
```

Any idea why this does not work?

Comment: does it work without the optfile part?

Comment: Can you show the contents of your files.txt? When using --optfile, the text file should contain the absolute path names.

Answer (score 5):

One alternative that may work for you would be to first create a virtual raster and then run `gdal_retile.py`

`gdalbuildvrt -te xmin_vrt ymin_vrt xmax_vrt ymax_vrt -srcnodata "0 0 0" your.vrt ./path/*.tif`

`gdal_retile.py -v -r bilinear -levels 8 -ps 512 512 -co "tiled=YES" -targetDir pyramid -co "COMPRESS=LZW" -targetDir pyramid ./path/your.vrt`

Comment: creative workaround! I like it. It won't generate pyramids for each input image though, just on the vrt, so may not work for some. See my answer for another alternative.

Answer (score 3):

from my testing: `Unrecognised command option: -` is because a filename in `files.txt` has a dash in it. Enclose the names in quotes ("this-is-an-image.tif") and it will work fine.

Unfortunately the [gdal_retile will not operate on multiple files](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4692) ticket seems to be true; perhaps give it a bump. Here is a Windows cmd line snippet to work around that:

```
for %a in (*.tif) do gdal_retile "%a" -targetDir pyramids
```

to use in batch file double up the percents, e.g. `%%a`

In Linux or Mac bash shell subst `a` and `$a` for `%` and separate phrases with `;` (courtesy of @decoder247):

```
for a in (*.tif); do gdal_retile $a -targetDir pyramids; done
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks for this. %a does not seem to work for me though in bash, what worked was: `for a in (*.tif); do gdal_retile $a -targetDir pyramids; done`

Comment: thanks @decoder247 for the bash expression. folded into the answer.