# Using gdal_retile

Tags: gdal

I have been trying to get gdal_retile working with the --optfile command. At first it did not work because in my files.txt I have '-' characters in the filename. I tried adding quotes around the files, and that seemed to work, but then gdal_retile would just freeze.

I have two questions:

1. Would using the --opfile command essentially be the same thing as calling gdal_retile from the command line once for every single file I have? Would I get the exact same results?
2. Does gdal2tiles do the same exact thing?

Answer (score 0):

1. The optfile is just added appended to the list of other arguments.  [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40447/optfile-not-working-with-gdal-retile) question may help.
2. Gdal2tiles creates raw tiles for use in web mapping that can be used directly with API's such as Google Maps.  gdal_retile creates tiles that sever software like geoserver can use.